# Using selected values in an Excel list box to formulate the legend

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to pass the selected values from a `list box` in `Excel` to legend in a chart. Specifically, I have data of certain companies in the following format

[image]

And I also have a list box, globalList, which contains the names of companies that can be selected. Selected companies' data will then be passed onto a chart using VBA.

[image]

However, the problems I encounter are in the following sections:

**Initialising a variable to hold values selected in the globalList**

```
listMax = globalList.ListCount - 1
`this creates the upper bound for the list box

For i = 0 To (globalList.ListCount - 1)
    If globalList.Selected(i) = True Then
        companiesSelected = companiesSelected + 1
    End If
    If i = listMax Then
    Exit For
    End If
Next i
`the above is used to retrieve the number of companies that have been selected by a user - whether =0 or > 0

Dim myLegend() As String
ReDim myLegend(0 To (globalList.ListCount - 1))
For i = 0 To (globalList.ListCount - 1)
    If globalList.Selected(i) = True Then
        myLegend(i) = globalList.List(i)
    End If
    If i = listMax Then
    Exit For
    End If
Next i
`this is the array object in which I intend to store company names selected in the list box.
```

The problem is that even though the above creates the `myLegend` string array, it also contains empty array items for the companies that may not have been selected by the user in the list box.
And even if I am able to remove these empty items from the array, the following problem occurs

**Passing the held values from my variable to my chart**

```
    For i = 1 To companiesSelected
    myChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = myLegend(i)
    Next i
```

Problem here is that `myLegend` array starts from 0, while `SeriesCollection` seems to start from 1. So I am unable to pass the string values for selected items to the legend of my chart's.

Could somebody please point out how to circumvent these problems?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code to extract the selected items into an [one-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type#Index_origin) array of String (without empty items):

```
Dim i           As Integer
Dim iCount      As Integer
Dim myLegend()  As String

iCount = 0
With globalList

    ReDim myLegend(1 To .ListCount)
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) = True Then
            iCount = iCount + 1
            myLegend(iCount) = .List(i)
        End If
    Next i

End With

If iCount > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve myLegend(1 To iCount)
Else
    ReDim myLegend(1 To 1)
    myLegend(1) = "Nothing here!"
End If
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for: the ReDim Preserve combination! Thank you ever so much! Wish I could +10!